# values are partially propagated to intermediate signal

Tags: vhdl

I have an entity called ***inbound*** that includes another entity called ***entity_A*** and a testbench ***tb*** for ***inbound***.

I have an alias in ***tb*** to the output of ***entity_A*** so I can have access to it as below:

```
ALIAS alias_entity_A_out IS
  <<SIGNAL .tb.inbound_inst.entity_A_inst.entity_A_out : INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE>>;
```

my problem is that the output intermediate signal (*entity_A_out_inst*) that used for instantiating ***entity_A*** in ***inbound*** is getting part of the values of *entity_A_out* output port, only two-bit are getting assigned and the rest are uninitialized, as below:

```
-- Instantiate entity_A
      entity_A_inst : ENTITY work.entity_A(rtl)
        PORT MAP(
          clk          => clk,
          reset        => reset,
          entity_A_in  => entity_A_in_inst,
          entity_A_out => entity_A_out_inst); -- here only part of the values are propogated
    

 # ** Note: rx_data in entity_A_out output port = 00000000
 # ** Note: rx_data in entity_A_out_inst intermediate signal = 00UUUUUU
 # ** Note: alias_rx_data = 00000000

 # ** Note: rx_data in entity_A_out output port = 00000001
 # ** Note: rx_data in entity_A_out_inst intermediate signal = 00UUUUUU
 # ** Note: alias_rx_data = 00000001
```

here is my code for ***inbound***:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

PACKAGE inbound_pkg IS

  TYPE RX_PORT_RECORD IS RECORD
    rx_data : UNSIGNED(7 DOWNTO 0);
    valid   : STD_LOGIC;
  END RECORD RX_PORT_RECORD;
  
  TYPE INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE IS RECORD
    rx_port : RX_PORT_RECORD;
  END RECORD INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE;
  
END PACKAGE inbound_pkg;

-----------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------

LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
USE work.inbound_pkg.ALL;

ENTITY entity_A IS
  PORT(clk          : IN  STD_LOGIC;  -- Main clock 
       reset        : IN  STD_LOGIC;  -- reset, active
       entity_A_in  : IN  INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE;
       entity_A_out : OUT INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE);
END ENTITY entity_A;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF entity_A IS
BEGIN
seq_proc: PROCESS (clk, reset)
  BEGIN -- for seq_proc
    IF (reset = '1') THEN
      entity_A_out.rx_port.rx_data <= (OTHERS => '0');
      entity_A_out.rx_port.valid   <= '0';
    ELSIF rising_edge(clk) THEN
      entity_A_out <= entity_A_in;
    END IF;
  END PROCESS seq_proc;
END ARCHITECTURE;

-----------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------

LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
USE work.inbound_pkg.ALL;

ENTITY inbound IS
  PORT(clk         : IN  STD_LOGIC;  -- Main clock 
       reset       : IN  STD_LOGIC;  -- reset, active
       inbound_in  : IN  INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE;
       inbound_out : OUT INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE);
END ENTITY inbound;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF inbound IS

  -- INTERNAL SIGNALS DECLARATION --
  SIGNAL entity_A_in_inst  : INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE; 
  SIGNAL entity_A_out_inst : INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE; -- this is the signal that is not working

BEGIN  -- start of architecture --
  -- for entity_A_in
  entity_A_in_inst.rx_port <= inbound_in.rx_port;
  -- for entity_A_out 
  inbound_out.rx_port <= entity_A_out_inst.rx_port;

  -- Instantiate entity_A
  entity_A_inst : ENTITY work.entity_A(rtl)
    PORT MAP(
      clk          => clk,
      reset        => reset,
      entity_A_in  => entity_A_in_inst,
      entity_A_out => entity_A_out_inst
    );
END ARCHITECTURE;
```

here is my code for ***tb***:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
USE work.inbound_pkg.ALL;

ENTITY tb IS
END ENTITY tb;

ARCHITECTURE sim OF tb IS
  SIGNAL clk   : STD_LOGIC := '0';
  SIGNAL reset : STD_LOGIC := '1';
  SIGNAL inbound_in_inst  : INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE := (rx_port => ((others => '0'), '0')); 
  SIGNAL inbound_out_inst : INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE;

ALIAS alias_entity_A_out IS
  <<SIGNAL .tb.inbound_inst.entity_A_inst.entity_A_out : INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE>>; 
  
BEGIN  -- start of architecture --
  
  inbound_inst : ENTITY work.inbound(rtl)
  PORT MAP(
    clk         => clk,
    reset       => reset,
    inbound_in  => inbound_in_inst,
    inbound_out => inbound_out_inst); 
      
  clk   <= NOT clk after 10 ns;
  reset <= '0' after 30 ns;
  
  test : PROCESS 
  begin
    WAIT UNTIL reset = '0'; 
    inbound_in_inst.rx_port.valid   <= '0';
    inbound_in_inst.rx_port.rx_data <= x"01";
    WAIT UNTIL rising_edge(clk);
    
    report "rx_data in entity_A_out output port = " & to_string(alias_entity_A_out.rx_port.rx_data);
    report "rx_data in entity_A_out_inst intermediat signal = " & to_string(<<SIGNAL .tb.inbound_inst.entity_A_out_inst : INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE>>.rx_port.rx_data);
    report "alias_rx_data = " & to_string(alias_entity_A_out.rx_port.rx_data);

    inbound_in_inst.rx_port.rx_data <= x"02";
    WAIT UNTIL rising_edge(clk);
    
    report "rx_data in entity_A_out output port = " & to_string(alias_entity_A_out.rx_port.rx_data);
    report "rx_data in entity_A_out_inst intermediat signal = " & to_string(<<SIGNAL .tb.inbound_inst.entity_A_out_inst : INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE>>.rx_port.rx_data);
    report "alias_rx_data = " & to_string(alias_entity_A_out.rx_port.rx_data);
    
    WAIT UNTIL rising_edge(clk);
    
    wait for 100 ns;
  END PROCESS test;
END ARCHITECTURE sim;
```

I don't understand what is the problem here but when I don't use ***Alias*** and declare a signal for entity_A_out in ***tb*** and use external name to assign to it, it works fine as below:

```
SIGNAL entity_A_out: INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE;
entity_A_out <= <<SIGNAL .tb.inbound_inst.entity_A_inst.entity_A_out : INBOUND_RECORD_TYPE>>;
```

here you can see it in EDA

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2CMT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks valid so this must be a bug with the simulator. If you switch to Riviera-PRO in EDA Playground it works as expected.

Comment: you are right. I use Modelsim Altera free edition. Thank you